# VBA Run Code non-stop

Tags: vba, while-loop

I am trying to write a program that runs indefinitely, till I stop it. For some reason it exited this while loop early (after 6 hours). A co-worker thinks it is because an error in the cpu, and I should use a Boolean flag instead of a string (less chance for the error). Is there any other suggestions?

```
If CommandButton1.Caption = "Start" Then
    CommandButton1.Caption = "Stop"
Else
    CommandButton1.Caption = "Start"
End If


While CommandButton1.Caption = "Stop"
    pause 1
    Range("C1").Value = Range("C1").Value + 1
    If Range("C1").Value = 300 Then
        Range("C1").Value = 0
        takeameasurement      ' This function did not cause the problem
    End If
Wend
```

(my pause function if you were wondering)

```
Function pause(time As Integer)
t = Timer + time      'wait for the table to settle before taking a measurement

Do While t > Timer
    DoEvents
Loop
End Function
```

Comment: Unless you have more details on what caused the loop to exit early, or why your co-worker thinks it's some kind of CPU error, I don't see how a change from `String` to `Boolean` will make it have `less chance for the error`.

Comment: The pause is still doing a pretty intensive loop. Have you tried importing sleep from kernel32, and using that to actively cede time to other processes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timer returns the number of seconds since midnight, so you may run into a problem if you call your `pause` function just before Timer loops back to zero.

Imagine only 100 seconds in a day and you call `pause` when `Timer = 99.5` - potentially you could end up with a value of `t` which is 100.5, in which case `t > Timer` will always be true and your Do loop never exits.

```
Function pause(time As Integer)
    t = Timer + time      

    Do While t > Timer
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Function
```

Comment: This!!! This totally what happened. I was time stamping all my measurements and I noticed it stop taking measurements around midnight. I should have mentioned this but I thought it was irrelevant.  Thanks!